# identifying data file type

Tags: file, text, notepad++, notepad

I have a huge 1.9 GB data file without extension I need to open and get some data from, the problem is this data file is extension-less and I need to know what extension it should be and what software I can open it with to view the data in a table.

here is the picture :

[image]

Its only 2 lines file, I already tried csv on excel but it did not work, any help ?

Comment: Not sure that this question is the best fit here. Perhaps you could ask it on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), or on a forum?

Answer (score 0):

I have never use it but you could try this:
http://mark0.net/soft-tridnet-e.html

explained here:
http://www.labnol.org/software/unknown-file-extensions/20568/

Answer (score 0):

The third "column" of that line looks 99% chance to be from php's print_r function (with newlines imploded to be able to stored on a single line).

There may not be a "format" or program to open it with if its just some app's custom debug/output log.

A quick google found a few programs to split large files into smaller units. THat may make it easier to load into something (may or may not be n++) for reading.

It shouldnt be too hard to mash out a script to read the lines and reconstitute the session "array" into a more readable format (read: vertical, not inline), but it would to be a one-off custom job, since noone other than the holder of your file would have a use for it.